# How to turn columns into row condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, unpivot

I have a column structure like so:

ID, c1(boolean), c2(boolean), c3(boolean), c4(boolean).

How can I turn the booleans into row conditions while reading from them? I only want the columns that were true.

i.e.

```
ID | c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5
107 true true false true false
```

I'd want to only return something like this:

```
ID | col
1   c1
1   c2
1   c4
```

I'm not sure if there's something like that in postgres.

Comment: Conditional expressions will help you (case when c1=true then 'c1' ...), see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-conditional.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use arrays for this.  I would simply do:

```
select t.id, v.colname
from t cross join lateral
     (values (c1, 'c1'), (c2, 'c2'), (c3, 'c3'), (c4, 'c4'), (c5, 'c5')
     ) v(val, colname)
where v.val;
```

This allows you to name your columns whatever you want.

Comment: This one is more malleable. Thanks, probably what I'm looking for.

Comment: Q: How do I go ahead and have distinct IDs?
I'm getting duplicates when I try this.

Comment: I.e.:
107, c1
107, c1
107, c2
107, c2

Comment: @Celestz . . . That would imply either that `t` has duplicate `id`s or that the `values()` statement has duplicate column names.

Comment: @Celestz . . . Then you might want `select distinct`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an array that is unnested:

```
select id, 'c'||t.idx as col
from the_table
  cross join unnest(array[c1,c2,c3,c4]) with ordinality as t(flag, idx)
where t.flag;
```

`with ordinality` returns the index of the value from the array. As that corresponds to the column "index", we can "re-create" the column name by using that in the output.

Online example: https://rextester.com/JJHG50564